# Postgres: convert a list of "name=value" values into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Convert this string:

```
n1=10;n2=50;n3=60;n4=20
```

using something like this (in Postgres 9.x):

```
select * 
  from (some_engine_to_convert_this('n1=10;n2=50;n3=60;n4=20')) t
```

to get a result like this:

```
Name Value
v1   10
v2   50
v3   60
v4   20
```

PS: I can't create any function, so I need to use Postgres built in functions only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select split_part(nv, '=', 1) as name,
       split_part(nv, '=', 2) as value
from (
  select unnest(string_to_array('n1=10;n2=50;n3=60;n4=20',';'))
) as t (nv);
```

`string_to_array` first creates an array of Key/Value pairs. `unnest` turns that into rows and the key/value elements are then extracted from the result using `split_part`.

Alternatively the combination of `unnest` and `string_to_array` can be combined using `regexp_split_to_table` but the regex functions are usually slower. Not sure which one would be more efficient here.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2991

Comment: string -> array -> rows -> split . Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer **:** taken from [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334922/3682599)

```
  with cte as(
  select unnest(string_to_array('n1=10;n2=50;n3=60;n4=20',';'))
  )
  select split_part(unnest, '=', 1) as name,
        split_part(unnest, '=', 2) as value 
  from cte
```